# Problems with ethernet Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ethernet

I am a newbie with Ubuntu and I am having a very weird problem, hopping you guys can help me out.

I set an Ethernet ip static for eth0

```
   addr 192.168.0.100
   mask 255.255.255.0
   gateway 192.168.0.100
```

When I connect my Ubuntu with my Ethernet network, everything is fine, I get the Ethernet connection.

My work also requires the Ethernet connection with another device, and now this is the strange thing. Everytime I reset my computer, I need to connect to the real Ethernet network, and then unplug the cable, plug in the other cable of my device. This way it works.

However, in case I do not plug the Ethernet network first, my computer cannot regconize the connection of my device.

I tried to manual setting the route, tried to configure the /etc/interfaces however nothing seems to be the solution for my problem.
I checked the route -n, it says that after the Ethernet network connection

```
   Des 0.0.0.0     gw 192.168.0.100 genmask 0.0.0.0
   Des 192.168.0.0 gw 0.0.0.0       genmask 255.255.255.0
```

These values are still the same when I unplug the network and then plug in my device. When I do not plug the Ethernet cable before the cable of my device, there is nothing in route-n

I hope that my question is not that confuse (it is hard to describe exactly what is the problem) so that you guys can understand my case.
Hoping that someone can give me an answer,
Have a nice day guys,

Answer (score 0):

thanks all for reading my question. Anyway, I found the solution after digging the Internet. Anyway, for someone that has the similar problem with me, you should check the version of the driver of the Ethernet and the version of the Ubuntu.

In my case, my computer uses the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and the Ethernet is Realtek Semiconductor RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller and the Kernal driver is r8169.

You should remove the driver and use the older version. r8168 works in my case.